# JPA CiteriaQuery join gives a wrong table name in the query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot

I have a problem related to criteriaquery usage.
This is my code

```
    VetPreferredLocation[] preffLoc = null;
    Predicate p1 = null;
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Vet> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Vet.class);
    Root<Vet> root = criteriaQuery.from(Vet.class);
    if (vet.getVetPreferredLocations() != null) {
        preffLoc = vet.getVetPreferredLocations().toArray(new VetPreferredLocation[0]);
        if (preffLoc != null && preffLoc[0].getZipcode() != null) {
            p1 = builder.like(/*companyRoot.join("products").get("category")*/
                    root.get("vetPreferredLocations").get("zipcode"), preffLoc[0].getZipcode());
        }
    }
    if (p1 != null) {
        criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get("qualification"), 
                builder.concat(root.get("user").get("firstName") + " ", root.get("user").get("lastName")), 
                root.get("hospitals").get("name"),
                builder.avg(root.get("ratings").get("rating"))).where(p1);
    }
    List<Vet> vets = null;
    try {
        vets = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return vets;
```

Here I am retrieving entities based on a filter. For this I have created a `Predicate` object.

This is the entity

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany//(mappedBy = "vet")
private Set<VetPreferredLocation> vetPreferredLocations = new HashSet<>();



public Set<VetPreferredLocation> getVetPreferredLocations() {
    return vetPreferredLocations;
}

public void setVetPreferredLocations(Set<VetPreferredLocation> vetPreferredLocations) {
    this.vetPreferredLocations = vetPreferredLocations;
}
```

**Not added complete set of members, getter setter, constructers etc
This is the joined entity

```
      @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "zipcode")
private String zipcode;

@Column(name = "locality")
private String locality;

@Column(name = "longitude")
private Float longitude;

@Column(name = "lattitude")
private Float lattitude;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "vet_id")
private Vet vet;
```

**appropriate getter setters etc present

When `root.get("vetPreferredLocations").get("zipcode")` is executed I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.vetPreferredLocations] of basic type
```

If I change root.get() to root.join(), the exception goes but the generated query has the wrong table name i.e. instead of `vet_preferred_location` I see `vet_vet_preferred_location`. This gives a table not found exception..

Please post your suggestions if any..